# YouTube Grid Gallery: How can I get the player to appear in a popup?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, youtube, gallery

I'm using the following code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
  swfobject.embedSWF(
      playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + 
      (autoplay?1:0), 'player', '290', '250', '9.0.0', false, 
      false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
}

function showMyVideos2(data) {
  var feed = data.feed;
  var entries = feed.entry || [];
  var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var title = entry.title.$t.substr(0, 15);
    var thumbnailUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
    var playerUrl = entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url;
    html.push('<li onclick="loadVideo(\'', playerUrl, '\', true)">',
              '<span class="titlec">', title, '...</span><br /><img src="', 
              thumbnailUrl, '" width="130" height="97"/>', '</span></li>');
  }
  html.push('</ul><br style="clear: left;"/>');
  document.getElementById('videos2').innerHTML = html.join('');
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    loadVideo(entries[0].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
    <object id="player"></object>
</div>
<div id="videos2"></div>
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/yerface/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=9">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

which is found here:http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/f3994f8078d20fe6.

What is the easiest way to have the player appear in a popup? I've been playing around with CSS options, using visible and display, but I can't seem to get it correct. Any tips for a newbie would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the player to be displayed on top of your content you could use `position: absolute;` in your CSS which takes it out of the document content flow. Then you use the `top` and `left` rules to place it where you like. Since you already know the dimensions of your popup, you can center it using javascript to calculate the top and left positions.

Good luck,
Per Flitig
Netlight Consulting

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer! The issue is not positioning the player. The issue is having the player only appear when a video is selected and having it disappear on close or when the video is finished. Any hints on how to do that? I've found ways to display a youtube video is a jquery popup but not in a gallery form.